# Add a class to a menu item depending on a body class

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, query, custom-post-type-archives

I need to have a class of current-menu-item added to a li with the id of #menu-item-127 if the body class is post-type-archive-team

I can do this with jQuery -

```
$(function(){
    if ($('body').hasClass('post-type-archive-team')) {
        $('#menu-item-127').addClass('current-menu-item');
    }
});
```

But it's needed before jQuery loads to make something else work.

Any ideas if I can do this with PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It'd be better not just to ask how to solve a problem, because that seems like a »*do my work for me*« question. Which isn't appreciated, see on topic at [help/on-topic] and [ask]. Best would be you present your research effort and if possible some code you've tried.

Comment: Why is this not possible with pure CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `nav_menu_css_class()` filter. The following function will add the current-menu-item class to a page identified by it's slug. You can

Update the `$cpt_name` and `$menu_item_id` variables to reflect your setup.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'nav_parent_class', 10, 2 );

function nav_parent_class( $classes, $item ) {
    $cpt_name = 'team';
    $menu_item_id = 127; // id of menu item to add current-menu-item class to

    if ( $cpt_name == get_post_type() && is_archive() && ! is_admin() ) {
        // remove any active classes from nav (blog is usually gets the currept_page_parent class on cpt single pages/posts)
        $classes = array_filter($classes, ($class == 'current_page_item' || $class == 'current_page_parent' || $class == 'current_page_ancestor'  || $class == 'current-menu-item' ? false : true ));

        // check if slug matches menu item id
        if( $item->ID == $menu_item_id ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
```